# How to resolve Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent?

Tags: node.js, multer

I am creating web service to send image with some text. I am sending file from postman then get this error **Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent**, req.body is empty & req.files undefined. This is screen shot of postman. ` [image]

controller code is here, to upload & validate image & some text data.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,'public/uploads/profile/');
    },
    filename : function(req,file,cb){
        if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg)$/)){
            var err = new Error();
            err.code = 'filetype';
            return cb(err);
        }else{
            cb(null,file.originalname + '_' + Date.now());
        }
    }
});
var upload = multer({
    storage : storage,
    limits : {fileSize : 10000000}
}).single('myFile');

userController.saveUser = function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
            if(err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE'){
                return res.json({success:false,message:'File sizee is too large. Max limit is 10mb'});
            }else if(err.code === 'filetype'){
                return res.json({success:false,message:'File type is invalid.'});
            }else{
                console.log(err);
                return res.json({success:'false',message:'File was not able to uploaded'});
            }
        }else{
            if(!req.files){
                return res.json({success:false,message:'No file selected!'});
            }else{
                return res.json({success:true,message:'File was uploaded successfully!'});
            }
        }
    });
    var params = req.body;

    user.findOrCreate({
        where:{
            first_name: helper.trimInputValue(params.first_name),
            email: helper.trimInputValue(params.email),
            boltt_code: helper.trimInputValue(params.boltt_code)
        },
        defaults:{
            first_name: helper.trimInputValue(params.first_name),
            middle_name : '',
            last_name : '',
            email: helper.trimInputValue(params.email),
            boltt_code: helper.trimInputValue(params.boltt_code),
            is_active : helper.trimInputValue(user.INACTIVE),
        }
    })
    .spread( function(user, created) {
        var msg = '';
        if(created){
            msg = 'User inserted successfully!';
        }else{
            msg = 'User already exist!';
        }
        res.send({
            message : msg,
            status:'Success',
            response:200,
            data : user
        });
    }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError,function(err){
        data = err.errors;
        var userError = Array();
        if(data.length){
            for(var key in data){
                userError.push({
                    'key' : data[key].path,
                    'message' : data[key].message
                });
            }
        }
        res.send({
            message : userError,
            status : 'Failure',
            response:200,
            data:[]
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.send({
            message : err, 
            status:'Failure',
            response : 500, 
            data:[]
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem, I need to write my insertion code in success block of upload.

```
userController.saveUser = function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
            if(err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE'){
                 res.send({success:false,message:'File sizee is too large. Max limit is 10mb'});
            }else if(err.code === 'filetype'){
                 res.send({success:false,message:'File type is invalid.'});
            }else{
                console.log(err);
                 res.send({success:'false',message:'File was not able to uploaded'});
            }
        }else{
            if(!req.files){
                 res.send({success:false,message:'No file selected!'});
            }else{
                var params = req.body;
                console.log(params);
                user.findOrCreate({
                    where:{
                        first_name: helper.trimInputValue(params.first_name),
                        email: helper.trimInputValue(params.email),
                        boltt_code: helper.trimInputValue(params.boltt_code)
                    },
                    defaults:{
                        first_name: helper.trimInputValue(params.first_name),
                        middle_name : '',
                        last_name : '',
                        email: helper.trimInputValue(params.email),
                        boltt_code: helper.trimInputValue(params.boltt_code),
                        is_active : helper.trimInputValue(user.INACTIVE),
                    }
                })
                .spread( function(user, created) {
                    var msg = '';
                    if(created){
                        msg = 'User inserted successfully!';
                        var mailOptions = {
                            from : 'test@boltt.com',
                            to : 'rajeev.web@boltt.com',
                            subject : 'New User Registered!',
                            html : '<b>Hello</b>'+ ' ' + user.dataValues.first_name + ' welcome to boltt family.'
                        };
                        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,info){
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                            console.log('Message %s sent : %s',info.messageId , info.response);
                        });
                    }else{
                        msg = 'User already exist!';
                    }
                    res.send({
                        message : msg,
                        status:'Success',
                        response:200,
                        data : user
                    });
                }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError,function(err){
                    data = err.errors;
                    var userError = Array();
                    if(data.length){
                        for(var key in data){
                            userError.push({
                                'key' : data[key].path,
                                'message' : data[key].message
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    res.send({
                        message : userError,
                        status : 'Failure',
                        response:200,
                        data:[]
                    });
                }).catch((err) => {
                    res.send({
                        message : err, 
                        status:'Failure',
                        response : 500, 
                        data:[]
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Validation code is working fine

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,'public/uploads/profile/');
    },
    filename : function(req,file,cb){
        if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(png)$/)){
            var err = new Error();
            err.code = 'filetype';
            return cb(err);
        }else{
            cb(null,file.originalname + '_' + Date.now());
        }
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage : storage,
    limits : {fileSize : 10000000}
}).single('image');
```

Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent, this error is occur because i was return json response two times. This error is also remove.  Now my code is working fine.